# Unable to Read QR Code Inside PDF with Length > 948 Characters Using ZXing Library - Getting "com.google.zxing.NotFoundException"

Tags: java

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to read a QR code embedded in a PDF file using the ZXing library. The problem occurs specifically when the QR code's length exceeds 948 characters. I consistently encounter the "com.google.zxing.NotFoundException" despite using the ZXing library.

Any insights or assistance regarding this issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Suggest some libraries or any method will be helpful